# How to use decltype with member functions

Tags: c++, function, instance, member, decltype

I'm trying to use decltype on member functions in Visual Studio 2012. I've stumbled upon a peculiarity and I'm wondering if this is intention or if it is a compiler bug. Consider (just a code snippet without meaning to show my point):

```
struct Test { int f() {return 0;} } T;
std::integral_constant<decltype(T.f()), 5>;
std::integral_constant<decltype(&Test::f), 5>; // error C2440
```

While the second line compiles, the third gives an error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int (__thiscall Test::*)(void)'

How come decltype on an instanciated call to a function yields its return type (this is what I am expecting), however trying to do the same without any member involved does yield a member function pointer? If this is the intended behavior, what is the reasoning behind it? How would I denote that I'm requesting the return type of a member function, without actually having an instance at hand? Of course I could do it the dirty way:

```
std::integral_constant<decltype(((Test*)nullptr)->f()), 5>;
```

But unquestionable this is pretty, pretty ugly and there should be a clean, straightforward C++ way to express this.

Comment: are you trying to extract the return type of f()?

Comment: Yep, that's what decltype is supposed to do if I'm right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&Test::f` does not call the member function `Test::f`. Instead, it [takes the address of the member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) and results in a [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions), which is of type `int (Test::*)()`.

In order to do what you want, you should use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval). The correct syntax is

```
std::integral_constant<decltype(std::declval<Test>().f()), 5>
```

Comment: Yep, THX, that solved it. Other than `&Test::f` I also tested leaving the address operator away and different other things, of course without any results. `std::declval` isn't mentioned in VS's help and I prematurely conclude it isn't there. However this isn't true, header `<type_traits>` has it.